# Deleting the last item from my recyclerView doesn't work?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

Hi guys i created a reccyclerView and in my recyclerView i'm able to add & delete items from sqlite database and from the recyclerView itself, everythig works fine but when i try to delete the last item the app crashes and i get Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException index:0 size:0. but the last item is successfully deleted from my sqlite database.

here is my **RecyclerViewAdapter**:

```
    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: LevelLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this)
        }
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            listener.onItemClick(position)
        }

        override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (v != null) {
                listener.onLongClick(position, v)
            }
            return true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LevelLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.tvLevel.text = todoList[position].name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todoList.size
    }

    fun deleteItem(position: Int) {
        todoList.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        if(todoList.size==0){
            todoList.clear()
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
        fun onLongClick(position: Int, view: View)
    }
```

In my **MainActivity** :

```
override fun onLongClick(position: Int, view: View) {
        val customDialog = Dialog(this)
        customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)

        val tvDelete = customDialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDelete)
       
        tvDelete.setOnClickListener {
            val id = MyDBHelper(this).readAllData()
            val myList = LevelModelClass(id[position].id, "")

            MyDBHelper(this).deleteLabel(myList)
            
            LevelAdapter(getItemList(), this).deleteItem(position)

            recyclerViewSetUp()

            customDialog.dismiss()
        }

 private fun recyclerViewSetUp() {
        if(getItemList().size > 0) {
            binding.rvLevel.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
            binding.rvLevel.adapter = LevelAdapter(getItemList(), this)

        }
    }

    private fun getItemList(): ArrayList<LevelModelClass> {
        val myDB = MyDBHelper(this)
        return myDB.readAllData()
    }
```

here is it the stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.teamup.projecttwo, PID: 28358
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
        at com.teamup.projecttwo.LevelAdapter.deleteItem(RecyclerViewAdapter.kt:46)
        at com.teamup.projecttwo.MainActivity$onLongClick$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:69)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post the stacktrace, friend! So people can see what's calling what to cause the crash. Also your ``deleteItem`` function should probably check if there's an item at ``position`` to delete, because ``removeAt`` will throw an exception like the one you're seeing (cant know for sure without the stacktrace though)

Comment: @cactustictacs sorry for that bcz but i posted what i'm sure is the reason for my problem and i'm sure what cause the problem is in my recyclerview adapter

Comment: if you post the stacktrace (the bit that says ``Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException index:0 size:0`` and all the lines that come after that) people will be able to tell you exactly where the problem is! Otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: @cactustictacs okay give me a sec

Comment: @cactustictacs okay i add the stacktrace and it seems as i told, the problem is in my adapter

Comment: Yeah it's like I guessed, you're getting a click on whatever ``tvDelete`` is when your adapter is empty, and it's trying to remove an item that doesn't exist. You need to either disable that button or whatever when the list is empty, or make ``deleteItem`` check the size of the list before it calls ``remove`` - or ideally, both! The size check is more important though - ``position`` can't ever be >= ``size``, because one item means ``size=1`` but it's located at index ``0``.

Comment: @cactustictacs can u write the deleteItem function for in case i didn't make it on my own. and thank u for ur help

Comment: @cactustictacs i disabled the tvDelete when mylist is empty and successfully make the app doesn't crash anymore but still the last item doesn't disppear from my recyclerview until add new one or restart the app

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with the help of @cactustictacs :)

in **RecyclerViewAdapter** change your deleteItem function to:

```
fun deleteItem(position: Int) {

        if(todoList.isNotEmpty() && todoList.size > position) {
            todoList.removeAt(position)
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        if(todoList.size == 0){
            todoList.clear()
        }

}
```

and in **MainActivity** do this code when tvDelete is clicked:

```
tvDelete.setOnClickListener {

            val id = MyDBHelper(this).readAllData()
            if( id.isEmpty() ) return@setOnClickListener
            val myList = LevelModelClass(id[position].id, "")
            MyDBHelper(this).deleteLev(myList)
            LevelAdapter(getItemList(), this).deleteItem(position)
            if( id.size == 1 ) binding.rvLevel.visibility = View.GONE
            recyclerViewSetUp()
            customDialog.dismiss()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code to delete an item:

```
val id = MyDBHelper(this).readAllData()
val myList = LevelModelClass(id[position].id, "")

MyDBHelper(this).deleteLabel(myList)
            
LevelAdapter(getItemList(), this).deleteItem(position)

recyclerViewSetUp()
```

I'm assuming the part that ends with `MyDBHelper(this).deleteLabel(myList)` is what deletes the item from your database, which you said is working.

This part:

`LevelAdapter(getItemList(), this).deleteItem(position)`

isn't affecting the adapter in your `RecyclerView` - it's creating a **new** adapter and deleting the item from *that* (which was causing the crash when `getItemList()` returned an empty list after deleting the last item from the DB). Your `RecyclerView` is unaffected.

But when you call `recyclerViewSetUp()` you create **another** new adapter from the current set of items in the DB, and display *that*. But when your item list is empty, `if(getItemList().size > 0)` fails and you don't change the adapter, so it still shows the old one with the last item in it. That's why you never see the last one get deleted.

---

You need to create *one* adapter and hold a reference to it somewhere, and call `deleteItem` on that instead

Comment: yeah u r right i already found a solution for that thank u so much i couldn't found without ur explaination